# Maximum or Minimum Re-attach

Tags: reattach

How many times do I need to re-attach? What is the necessary thing to do in order to help my transaction get confirmed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed number of reattachings to have it processed. The recomendation is to keep reattaching every 30 minutes to 1 hour after the transaction is sent, this way the tip algorithm is more likely to select this transaction because it will be "fresh", since the reattachment proccess will re-do PoW.